# whats is topology of $[0,1]$ in Urysohn Lemma?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Urysohn Lemma is

> A topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is normal if and only if for every
> pair of disjoint nonempty closed subsets $C, D \subseteq X$ there is a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow [0, 1]$
> such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in C$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in D$.

are there some limits for the topology of $[0,1]$? if the topology of $[0,1]$ is trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$,  i think such $f$ always exists?

so my question is that does Urysohn Lemma means for any topology of $[0,1]$ there is always such $f$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not valid for any topology. The topology used here is the standard topology, the one induced from the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: the standard topology is that the collection of all unions of open interval on $\mathbb{R}$?, i see some proof use the different open set on $[0,1]$, i am so confuse!

Comment: Yes, that's the standard topology. Where did you see a proof that uses different open sets?

Comment: http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/notes/13-urysohn.pdf  use the open interval $(a,b)$,  then  http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/UrysohnLemma_v5.pdf uses $(a,1]$ or $[0,a)$

Comment: Since $(a,1]=(a,2)\cap[0,1]$ and $[0,a)=(-1,a)\cap[0,1]$, $(a,1]$ and $[0,a)$ belong to the topology of $[0,1]$. And that's consistence with what I wrote, since $(a,1]$ and $[0,a)$ are open intervals in $[0,1]$. Yes, they are not open in $\Bbb R$, but what matters here is that they are open in $[0,1]$.

Comment: oh, i got it, its subspace of $\mathbb{R}$,thank u so much!!!!!

Comment: @maple it’s also just the order topology on $[0,1]$ where the mon and max have slightly different neighbourhoods.

Comment: @hennobrandsma thank u ,security researcher!

Comment: @maple stilll a topologist in my free time, though...

Comment: @hennobrandsma i am security researcher...but young. can i get your contact like email? i am so happy! u are the second man who both like security and topology.the first is me, hahaha...